# Where to put PHP code in an HTML File (For a Contact Form)?

Tags: php, html

I have an html file (i.e. index.html). I have html code for my contact form (i.e. name, email, etc.. fields). Where do I put my PHP code without turning the index.html into a index.php file, if it is possible?

Comment: Please show us the `html` code for your form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the php code to be interpreted instead of being shown, then somehow the http server answering the request to that file has to know that is it meant to start interpretation of the code. Typically that is done using the file name extension `.php`.

You certainly *could* configure your http server such that the same will be performed when `.html` files are requested. But that would be a very bad approach. Don't do it.

So rename your file to `index.php` and go with that. It is easiest, transparent and robust.

If you are concerned with how your URL looks, then take a look at "rewriting" and "pretty URLs" which allow to use URLs like `http://my.server/index` or simply `http://my.server/` for the same. Rewriting inside the http server takes care to internally map such requests to your `index.php` file without changing the URL visible in the users browser.

However there is one thing I would like to mention here, since I often see beginners to fall into a that issue: if that `php` code of yours only contains the processing of a posted form, so maybe validation and storage, then there is absolutely no reason to put it into the same file as the html markup! In contrary, don't! Use a separate file for processing, after having processed forward the browser to another view. Only if you need dynamic values getting inserted into your html markup, then it makes sense to embed php into your markup. That is exactly what php was originally created for and you should do that by means of turning your static html files into php files (`.php` name extension).

Comment: But wouldn't my page be slower to load since the page has to be interpreted as a php file rather than an html file?

Comment: It would be delivered slower than a static html file, yes. But if you want your php code to be interpreted then there is no way around it. The html part of the file will _not_ get interpreted, so there is no performance penalty there. It is only the php part that gets interpreted and that is nothing you can get around, however you call the file.

Comment: Is it possible to create a separate php file and link to that from my html file in the header?

Comment: That depends on what that php code does. I added something about that to the answer above. But it is hard to specify details with your vague description. You would have to add more details to your question about what that php code actually does, what it is there for.

Comment: One clear statement: if you only hesitate to rename the file because of performance considerations, then forget it. The overhead of some static html getting parsed too compared to a "pure php file" is probably something like far than 1% of the total effort. Not worth thinking about that. Actually all modern web frameworks do deliver even static html via php and dynamic views.

Comment: So for a simple contact form, it would not require dynamic values, so it would be recommended to process the values from the html file in a separate php file?

Comment: Absolutely "Yes" in that case.

Comment: If I do that, would I need additional javascript code grab the data from the html fields and send it to the php code?

Comment: You can use javascript and that allows much more flexibility like client side validation and visualization. But you do not have to, you can use a plain `<form>` html tag and simply specify the processing php file as `action` attribute in there. Then the form gets sent to that script upon submission. So something like: `<form action="/path/to/process_contact_form.php" method="post">...</form>`.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by client side validation?

Comment: You have to validate the content a user fills into your form. Different things you want to validate, some examples: has a return email address been entered at all? Is it a usable email address or just nonsense? You can do that on the server side or on the client side. Both has advantages and disadvantages. Client side validation is more more lightweight and convenient for the user, since there is no full page reload every time the submit button is pressed. Also visualizing the things that have to be changed before a submission is much easier on the client side.

Comment: So if a user had to enter a captcha code before submitting their email, it would be better to have javascript code so the page doesn't refresh each time?

Comment: Some captcha is something different, since that is a security measurement. A user could always work around that captcha when it is validated on the client side. So that certainly is something that has to be validated on the server side. I referred to missing input in mandatory fields where it makes sense to note that to the user but where nothing dramatic happens if it gets submitted nonetheless.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not that difficult.

1) In your opening form tag `<form action="contact-proc.php" method="post" name="contact" id="contact">` make sure you have an action (the processing page that collects the data and sends the email).

html page sample

```
<form action="contact-proc.php" method="post" name="contact" id="contact">
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="5px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"><strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font>Name:</strong></div></td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" size="35" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"><strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font>E-Mail Address:</strong></div></td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" size="35" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"><strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font>Message:</strong></div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="10" wrap="virtual"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><div align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send" /></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

2) Create a page to process the data and send the email. In this case `contact-proc.php`

3) On the processing page include something like this...

```
<?php
$email = 'your-email-address@domain.ext';
$domain = 'your-domain-name'; // ie: google.com
$strVisitorInfo = ''.
"Customer Service Request from Your WebSite\r\n\r\n" .
"Name    : ".$_POST['name']."\r\n" .
"E-Mail   : ".$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
"Comments : \r\n" .
$_POST['comments'];

$to = $Email;
$subject = "Customer Service Request from Your WebSite";
$headers = 'From: noreply@'.$domain . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: noreply@'.$domain . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $strVisitorInfo, $headers);
?>
```

Where `$_POST['name']` `$_POST['email']` & `$_POST['comments']` are the name of the form elements on your `html` page. You can change those to match your form.

On your processing page you can include some information letting the visitor know that there email has been sent. Like...

```
<div align="center">Thank you <?php echo $_POST['name'] ?>.<br>
Your email has been sent. We will be in touch with you soon.
</div>
```

Of course you will want to do some validation to make sure empty forms and other nonsense are submitted. But that's a different question than what is asked here.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out so much. I just have one question, where do I put the PHP file in the directory? If I put it into a folder called "PHP", how would I link it to the HTML file? 
Thanks

Comment: The PHP (processing) file should be in the same directory as your html file. However, wherever you put it, just make sure your form action link points to it correctly.